# Moq - Setup Generic Return type

Tags: c#, .net, moq

How do you Setup a generic returntype in Moq?

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   T Bar<T>();
}
```

Now I want to setup `Bar<T>()` to work inside a test

```
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
foo.Setup(x => x.Bar<It.IsAnyType>()).Returns(new Mock<???>().Object);
```

How do I fill out `???`, or if that is not possible, then how do I return a generic mock?

There are 100s of types, I am trying to avoid mocking them all.
The test breaks (because the code throws and exception) if the call returns null for any type, which is sadly the default non-mocked behavior.

Comment: Assuming this is for a unit test, your expectation of any type is a bit broad. You should at least know the type for the test. This might just be an xy problem. Can you show an actual representation of type and test.

Comment: Is T a reference type? ie `where T: class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T` is a reference type ie

```
public interface IFoo {
    T Bar<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Then it would be easier to just create a slim mock

```
public class MockFoo : IFoo {
    private MockFoo() {

    }

    public T Bar<T>() where T : class => Mock.Of<T>();

    public static IFoo New() => new MockFoo();
}
```

which can be initialized while arranging the test and using MOQ for mocking the output of `Bar`

```
//Arrange
IFoo foo =  MockFoo.New();

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `Returns` overload: `IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns(InvocationFunc valueFunction);`

Setup:

```
 factory.Setup(m => m.Create<It.IsAnyType>())
        .Returns(new InvocationFunc(invocation =>
                 {
                     var typeArgument = invocation.Method.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                     return Activator.CreateInstance(typeArgument);
                 });
```

Call:

```
 var something = factory.Object.Create<Something>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As was stated before, a reference type is required to create a mock:

```cs
public interface IFoo
{
    T Bar<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Now, it is possible to create a `Mock<T>` using reflection.
This is really ugly, but it works also when interfaces are passed as `T`.

```cs
var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
fooMock
    .Setup(foo => foo.Bar<It.IsAnyType>())
    .Returns(new InvocationFunc(call =>
    {
        // create type Mock<T> with the type passed to Bar<T>
        var typeArg = call.Method.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var mockType = typeof(Mock<>).MakeGenericType(typeArg);
        var mock = Activator.CreateInstance(mockType);

        // find "Object" property, call get
        var objectProperty = mockType.GetProperty(nameof(Mock.Object), typeArg);
        return objectProperty.GetValue(mock);
    }));
```